# Why do cutoff frequencies of a high-pass digital filter differ from the ones i used to transform it from a low-pass analog filter in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, filters, lowpass-filter, digital-filters, highpass-filter

I need to transform an elliptic analog low-pass filter to a digital high-pass filter but i'm having a problem because the resulting filter has lower cutoff frequencies than the ones i set. Here is the code sample from MATLAB:

```
Fs = 44100; %Sampling rate
Rp = 0.05; 
Rs = 60;

Wp = 2*pi*10000; %Cutoff frequencies of my high-pass filter
Ws = 2*pi*9700;

WsE= Wp/Ws; %LP->HP transformation for the analog stopband frequency
WpE=1

k=sqrt(1-(WpE/WsE)^2); %Elliptic filter calculation of N
D=(10^(0.1*Rs)-1)/(10^(0.1*Rp)-1);
q0=(1/2)*((1-sqrt(k))/(1+sqrt(k)));
q=q0+2*q0^5+15*q0^9+150*q0^13;
N=ceil(log10(16*D)/(log10(1/q)));

[z,p,k]=ellipap(N,Rp,Rs); %Making the analog prototype
bE=k*poly(z);aE=poly(p);

[bE,aE]=lp2hp(bE,aE,Wp); %Transforming the low-pass into a high-pass
[bd,ad]=bilinear(bE,aE,Fs);

Ndigital = 20000;
[h,w]=freqz(bd,ad,Ndigital);
H=abs(h);

f = w/(2*pi)*Fs; % Ploting the filter
figure(1);
plot(f,20*log10(H), 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('Hz');
ylabel('|H(z)|');
pause
```

and i am expecting a filter with my desired frequencies but get this:
[image: High-Pass Filter Resulting from the Code]

I can't pin-point the problem in the code. Why am i getting these results and how do i fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bilinear transform warps the frequency axis, that's why cut-off frequencies of the analog filter are not necessarily mapped to the correct frequencies in the digital domain. You can use the prewarping option by providing an optional parameter to `bilinear.m`. Check the corresponding [mathworks documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bilinear.html).